# Illegal assigment from Object to String

Tags: apex, history-tracking, aura-enabled

I'm trying to update a field with the OldValue, but I'm receiving the following error: **Illegal assigment from Object to String**

```
@AuraEnabled    
public static String updateRecordAfterReturned(Id recordId){
    if (bankaccRcd == null){
        bankaccRcd = [SELECT Id, Status__c, Observations__c FROM Bank_Account_Request__c WHere Id =: recordId];    
    }
    try {
        List<Bank_Account_Request__History> bar = new List<Bank_Account_Request__History>();
        bar = [SELECT ParentId, OldValue, NewValue, Field, CreatedById, CreatedDate FROM Bank_Account_Request__History 
               WHERE ParentId = :recordId and Field = 'Status__c' LIMIT 1];  
        bankaccRcd.Status__c = bar[0].OldValue; // error line
        update bankaccRcd;    
        return 'Success';
    }catch (DmlException e){
        Return 'Error: '+e.getMessage();
    }
    
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: if you look in the Object Reference for any of the xxxHistory objects, you'll see the type of OldValue and NewValue is `anyType` which in Apex is `Object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think history tracking object's oldvalue field return datatype is an object, Therefore it is returning object as a value.
What you can do is, you can convert/typecast the object to a string or any other data type and assign that to your field or variable.

for example.

```
bankaccRcd.Status__c = String.valueOf(bar[0].OldValue);
```

or

```
bankaccRcd.Status__c = (String) bar[0].OldValue;
```

Note* if you try to typecast a sObject into a string it will throw a runtime exception of invalid conversion however you can convert a sObject to a string by using String.valueOf(object) method.

Comment: +1 from me. Better a cast `(String) bar[0].OldValue` as otherwise there is the possibility of `null` being turned into the string `'null'`.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you, Bilal Malik! It helped me a lot.

Comment: @KeithC even with typecast if the value is null it will be turned into the string 'null'

Comment: @SabrinaT. Happy to help.

Comment: @BilalMalik You are right that there is no difference, though from this quick test both return `null` not `'null'`. Code: `Object o = null; System.assertEquals(null, (String) o, 'cast'); System.assertEquals(null, String.valueOf(o), 'valueOf');`.